# grails test-app can't find .class file of base class that it is testing

Tags: grails, spock

I'm new to Grails (and Java), so it is probably something simple, like a missing configuration somewhere..., but I haven't been able to Google a result so far, most hits on the "Failed to read candidate component class" seems to be related to grails and plugins, not "user" code, so I don't assume it's a version issue or a plug-in failure.

I'm trying to run "grails test-app" on the open source OpenTele server code (https://bitbucket.org/4s/opentele-server/src), but I get an error in about 20 of the 1001 test cases.  The errors are all similar to:

```
Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/mike/OpenTele/Bitbucket
/4s-opentele-server/target/test-classes/functional/pages/questionnaire/ListPage.class];
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource 
[pages/ScaffoldPage.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I read this as it can't find the ScaffoldPage.class file, but if I search for it, I can see it:

```
mike@ubuntu:10:27:23:~/OpenTele/Bitbucket/4s-opentele-server$ find | grep "ScaffoldPage.class"
./target/test-classes/functional/pages/ScaffoldPage.class
 mike@ubuntu:10:27:35:~/OpenTele/Bitbucket/4s-opentele-server$
```

I'm using grails 2.1.0.

A full example of the error I get is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/mike/OpenTele/Bitbucket/4s-opentele-server/target/test-classes/functional/pages/questionnaire/ListPage.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [pages/ScaffoldPage.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at grails.buildtestdata.mixin.BuildTestDataUnitTestMixin.findDomainSubclasses(BuildTestDataUnitTestMixin.groovy:221)
at grails.buildtestdata.mixin.BuildTestDataUnitTestMixin.findDomainClassesToMock_closure5(BuildTestDataUnitTestMixin.groovy:100)
at grails.buildtestdata.mixin.BuildTestDataUnitTestMixin.findDomainClassesToMock(BuildTestDataUnitTestMixin.groovy:98)
at grails.buildtestdata.mixin.BuildTestDataUnitTestMixin.mockForBuild(BuildTestDataUnitTestMixin.groovy:70)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension$FixtureType$FixtureMethodInterceptor.intercept(JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension.java:145)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [pages/ScaffoldPage.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I tried running "grails test-app -clear" but it didn't change the result...

The program runs fine with either "grails run-app" or by doing a "grails war" and then running it in tomcat.

Any hints would be appreciated.